# PHPUnit and WebDriver - what's the difference between value() and keys()

Tags: selenium, input, phpunit, textfield

In PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase, there're two methods used to input some string in textfield.
What's the difference?
Should I use the keys() method to emulate human behavior?

Answer (score 1):

To emulate human behavior I would use this for example:

```
$this->$driver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys('TEXT INPUT HERE');
$this->$driver->getKeyboard()->pressKey(WebDriverKeys::ENTER);
```

Here's you'll get to the point where you emulate that you press keys on your keyboard.
With ' TEXT INPUT HERE ' you can type whatever you like to type in the textfield.

Comment: As per question, please describe difference between value() and keys(). Thanks